# Producing (bibliometric) statistics on bibliography entries, how to do it in pure latex or with some packages but no external biblio management tools

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, packages, overleaf, bibliographystyle

I would like to produce statistics on a variety of stuff on my document's bibliography. I am using bibtex (in overleaf) and have little idea from where to start. What I want to obtain are these:

1. Count number of references of bibliography.bib cited and number of not cited (even though at the end of my document I have `\nocite{*}`.
2. Count the number of `@article`, `@inproceedings`, `@book` etc. type of references in .bib file.
3. Do an estimated sum of `pagetotal` of all references. For all the references where that field is missing, extract it from difference in the pages interval `pages = {5--16}` for example `= 16-5+1 = 12`. If `pages` interval is also not present, consider `pagetotal` equal to the calculated average of the `pagetotal` (and diffs of `pages`) in the references where those fields are present - and subsequently calculate the total sum.
4. Count number of references for each year starting from the oldest (least recent) in the .bib to the most recent year (maybe a column graph here would also make sense, like a distribution).
5. Count number of references in each language (e.g.: `language = {english}`: 30 references, `language = {french}`: 5 references etc.).
6. Count number of references cited in each chapter.
7. Count number of references in which appears the word "documentation", like `note = {Online documentation.}`.
8. Count number of references containing urls ending with ".pdf", which might be in fields like `url = {some.site/file.pdf}` but may also like `note = {File in \url{someothe.site/anotherfile.pdf}.}`.

I would prefer to obtain these without external software for bibliography management. Any tex package indication or vanilla tex defined functions are welcomed.

Comment: For anyone interested I found this [`totalcount`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/totalcount) package that might help.

Also see [`this question`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279019/re-inserting-a-counter-value-that-preceeds-the-counter-environment-in-a-latex-d) for ideas...